# Java json parse

Tags: java, json, parsing

Well I've been trying for like 3 hours now. Using lots of apis it still doesn't work.

I'm trying to parse

```
{
  "id": 8029390,
  "uid": "fdABNhroHsr0",
  "user": {
    "username": "Skrillex",
    "permalink": "skrillex"
  },
  "uri": "/skrillex/cat-rats",
  "duration": 305042,
  "token": "VgA2a",
  "name": "cat-rats",
  "title": "CAT RATS",
  "commentable": true,
  "revealComments": true,
  "commentUri": "/skrillex/cat-rats/comments/",
  "streamUrl": "http://media.soundcloud.com/stream/fdABNhroHsr0?stream_token=VgA2a",
  "waveformUrl": "http://w1.sndcdn.com/fdABNhroHsr0_m.png",
  "propertiesUri": "/skrillex/cat-rats/properties/",
  "statusUri": "/transcodings/fdABNhroHsr0",
  "replacingUid": null,
  "preprocessingReady": null
}
```

in to an array/list.
Any help?

Comment: Is that one entry in the list?

Comment: What APIs or libraries have you been using? Why doesn't it work? [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: gson, flexjson and a lot more. I'm a bit of a newbie when it comes to java (More of a php person <.<)

Comment: This is valid JSON according to python's `json` module.  Do you mean that it won't parse, or that the contents don't meet your requirements?

Comment: Well with gson it just said it couldn't deser' it. So yea, I kinda have no idea what's wrong.

Comment: Show us what have you tried till now.

Comment: The JSON you show in your question is valid JSON for one element.  It will not parse into an arraylist.  Instead it will parse into one element.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm using Jackson from http://codehaus.org/ and so far it has lived up to all my needs.

You don't quite deal with json as raw strings in an arraylist, but rather as POJOs, here's a quick example with a subset of your json.

```
public class JacksonExample {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonParseException, JsonMappingException, IOException {
        String text = "{ \"id\": 8029390, \"user\": { \"username\": \"Skrillex\" } }";

        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        Pojo pojo = mapper.readValue(text, Pojo.class);

        System.out.println(pojo.id);
        System.out.println(pojo.user.username);
    }
}

class Pojo {
    public String id;
    public User user;

    public String getId() { return id; }
    public void setId(String id) { this.id = id; }

    public User getUser() { return user; }
    public void setUser(User user) { this.user = user; }

    public static class User {
        public String username;

        public String getUsername() { return username; }
        public void setUsername(String username) { this.username = username; }
    }
}
```

The mapper creates a Pojo object with the values filled in. Then you can use that object for anything you need.

Here are a couple of links for the Jackson project:

http://jackson.codehaus.org/

http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonInFiveMinutes

The latest all in one JAR is here:

http://jackson.codehaus.org/1.9.1/jackson-all-1.9.1.jar

Answer (score 1):

You should try JavaJson from source forge... you can parse that this way:

```
JsonObject json = JsonObject.parse("...");
/*
 * or also JsonObject.parse(inputStream);
 */
then you can get fields this way:
String title = json.getString("title");
String username = json.get("user", "username").toString();
```

and so on. here's the link: https://sourceforge.net/projects/javajson/